# Kodi 16 install from sources

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, kodi

I am trying to install `Kodi 16` from a `tar.gz` file because if I try from PPA it automatically installs Kodi 18 version.

I do exactly as it says on your guides but firstly I didn't find the configure file on the folder as the guide says.

I found the configure file at `lib/libmpeg2` I execute exactly the same instructions but after running:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

I get errors after running `make install`as shown:

[image]

Comment: Give me a few minutes, and I'll investigate. Is the ultimate goal to install Kodi 16 regardless of the method? Or is it to install Kodi via the compiler?

Comment: i just want to install Kodi 16 i don't care how it will be installed i only want to install this version!!

Comment: i have also uploaded the terminal printscreen

Comment: OK. I'll look into it.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: @Γιάννης - I've done some research as requested, and posted an [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/883598/606721) with a proper official PPA that contains Kodi 16.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official PPA for Kodi Jarvis (16.1) available.

You can install it from your Terminal like this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/kodi-old

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install kodi
```

**nb.** *Please make sure to remove the other PPA's for Kodi, as they will conflict with this one.*